# How to set max user connections in python environment?

Tags: python, mysql, heroku, mysql-python, cleardb

Currently I am working on a bot using **mysql connector** , which is python library that allows you to communicate with mysql. I am running **ClearDB** on **Heroku**.
 Sometimes while I am running certain commands I run into the following error.

> Error Code: 1226 User 'b450a27c71705e' has exceeded the
>   'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 10)

While this error hasn't seemed to stop any of my commands from running , i'd rather change the allowed amount of user connections before it does.
Unfortunately , the only answers I can find are for PHP , which is ,

```
SET GLOBAL max_user_connections = 100;
```

Any idea how to replicate this in python?

Comment: Could you provide code for what you are doing? Is it possible that you are opening more connections than needed?

Comment: My program code is running in the thousands , i get this error on and off , so im assuming that it's not opening much more than 10, which is why it's still running, and since my program will only get bigger , i'm thinking the best solution would be to allow more connections in case of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a ClearDB plan that only permits 10 connections.
The only path they offer is to upgrade to a ClearDB plan that offers more connections. If you're on Mercury, upgrade to Jupiter or Saturn. If in doubt, post your question to the ClearDB Support system. They will be able to help you best.

The multi-tenant systems will not permit you to modify this parameter.